# How can I compute the mean of a sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability

Suppose that I have a sequence of random variables where $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ where the pdf of $X_n$ is equal to:

$$
 f_n(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    (n-1)/2       & \quad \  -1/n < x < 1/n \\
    1/n  & \quad n < x < n+1\\
    0 & \quad otherwise
  \end{cases}
$$

I am trying to find $E(X_n)$. Here, I tried the computation by doing:

$$
E(X_n) = \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}x\frac{(n-1)}{2} dx + \int_{n}^{n+1}x\frac{1}{n} dx
$$

However, this method doesnt yield the correct answer, which should be $1+ \frac{1}{2n}$. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Update: I am providing my answer here:
$$
 \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}x\frac{(n-1)}{2} dx =  \frac{(n-1)}{2}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}x dx = \frac{(n-1)}{2}\cdot 2 \cdot\frac{x^2}{2}\rvert_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{(n-1)}{2n^2}
$$
and
$$
 \int_{n}^{n+1}x\frac{1}{n} dx = \frac{1}{n}\frac{x^2}{2}\rvert^{n+1}_{n} = \frac{2n+1}{2n}
$$

But when I add the two, I get $\frac{2n^2+2n-1}{2n^2}$, which is different than the answer. Does anyone have any ideas what happened?

Comment: This method *does* yield the correct answer. I can't tell you what you are doing wrong until you show your work.

Comment: Your first integral should be $0$.  Into $x^2$, plug in $(1/n)$, take away the result of plugging in $(-1/n)$. With less work: the first integral is $0$, since we are integrating the odd function $x$ over an interval symmetric about $0$.

Comment: thanks, I totally didn't know how to compute integrals for a second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally solving the first integral without being clever at all,
the result is
$$
\left.\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{2} \right\rvert_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac 1n}.
$$
You rewrote this as
$$
\left.\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot 2 \frac{x^2}{2} \right\rvert_{0}^{\frac 1n}
$$
which is not correct, because
$$
\left.\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot\frac{x^2}{2} \right\rvert_{-\frac 1n}^{0}
\neq \left.\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot\frac{x^2}{2} \right\rvert_{0}^{\frac 1n}.
$$
It's not clear what led you astray, perhaps looking at the $x^2$
in the solution and noticing that
$\left(-\frac 1n\right)^2 = \left(\frac 1n\right)^2$,
which is true, but that actually implies that
$$
\left.\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot\frac{x^2}{2} \right\rvert_{-\frac 1n}^{0}
= -\left.\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot\frac{x^2}{2} \right\rvert_{0}^{\frac 1n}
$$
(notice the very important negative sign right after the equals sign!)
because $-\frac 1n$ is the *lower* end of its interval
while $\frac 1n$ is the *upper* end of its interval.

As noted in a comment, it is much easier to simply recognize that you
are integrating an odd function over a neighborhood of $0$ and
conclude that the result is zero.